# Export symbol declaration in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In a project I'm working on, I'm using symbols to flag functions to determine whether the code should use the function expression itself or call it and use the returned value. Currently it looks like so:

```
const shouldEvaluate: unique symbol = Symbol('evaluate');

interface FlaggableFunction extends Function {
    [shouldEvaluate]?: boolean
}
```

While this works, when I enable declarations in my config, I get the error `semantic error TS4033 Property '[shouldEvaluate]' of exported interface has or is using private name 'shouldEvaluate'.`. It works if I export this symbol, however it also gets exported into the compiled JS, which I do not want. Is there a way export a symbol only to the declaration file while keeping it private in the compiled JS?

So far, I've tried declaring the type and initiating the variable separately

```
export declare let shouldEvaluate: unique symbol;
shouldEvaluate = Symbol('evaluate');
```

but this gives me an error that a unique symbol must be declared using const. I also tried giving `FlaggableFunction` in index signature like so:

```
interface FlaggableFunction extends Function {
    [key: unique symbol]: boolean
}
```

but that throws `TS1023 An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I realized that I could've easily just moved the flags into a separate file and exported them, since in my situation I was more concerned about keeping a single default export in the entry file than I was about exposing the flags. Below was my previous attempt, which was kind of a mess.

---

It took some work, but I've gotten to a solution that kind of works. Basically, I moved all code references to those symbols outside into their own private functions, and am using an object literal to map to those symbols.

```
const shouldEvaluate: unique symbol = Symbol('evaluate');

const flags: { [key: string]: symbol } = {
    evaluate: shouldEvaluate
};

// Switched to a single Flaggable type that takes a generic type instead of creating multiple so it an be passed into the setFlag function
export type Flaggable<T> = T & {
    [shouldEvaluate]?: boolean
}

function setFlag(val: Flaggable<any>, flag: string) {
    const symbol: symbol = flags[flag];
    val[symbol] = true;
}
```

So now in the exported class, instead of setting the symbol as a property on the function directly, I'm using the setFlag function.

```
export default class MyClass {
    setEvalFlag (func: Flaggable<Function>): Flaggable<Function> {
        setFlag(func, 'evaluate');
        return func;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a sidenote, I also tried this using _just_ an object, but assigning a symbol to a property with type `unique symbol` throws an error. I submitted an issue as this seemed like a bug. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23388

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way export a symbol only to the declaration file while keeping it private in the compiled JS?

When you do `export declare let shouldEvaluate: unique symbol;` It becomes public anyways.

So no, you cannot use a private variable that is part of a public type.

You can *keep everything private*. But that is not what you want.